# How to pass POST request to constructor in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, request

I'd like to access a request variable from the constructor of my controller in Laravel. How can I do this?

this is my route:

```
Route::post('bookGetById',     ['uses' => 'v1\BookController@getBookById']);
```

and here is my controller:

```
public function __construct(Request $request = null)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->bookStructure = new bookStructure($request->imageHeight);
}
```

but the request variable is always null. How can I pass the request into the constructor?

Comment: Any specific reason for trying this?

Comment: You wont be able to as Laravel is not injecting the request to the constructor as you route it to the controller method `getBookById`. You could try `['uses'=>'v1\BookController@__construct']`. Should work but seems pointless

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what version of laravel you're using but I think in 5.2+ the controller is created before the request is bound. There's a workaround:

```
public function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
   $this->middleware(function (Request $r, $next) {
        $this->bookStructure = new bookStructure($request->imageHeight);
        return $next($r);
   });
}
```

However I would recommend doing this is via the service container:

File **AppServiceProvider**

```
$this->app->bind("bookstructure.withheight", function ($app) {
   return new bookStructure($app->make("request")->get("imageHeight",0));
});
```

You can instantiate your bookStructure wherever you need it via:

```
 app()->make("bookstructure.withheight");
```

Answer (score -1):

I know you are asking how to pass a request to a class constructor but you may want to rethink it and pass it to a controller that validates the request and instantiates your class with validated request variables.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I did however flag this as not an answer because it should be a comment to the question and not an answer.